# Why did one $ disappear?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```js
let str = '$$double_dollars$$'
console.log(str.replace('$$double_dollars$$', '$$no_double_dollars$$'));
// => $no_double_dollars$
// expected $$no_double_dollars$$
```

Why is this happening? How to work around this bug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure str.replace is interpreting $ has a Regular expression special character ($ means the string must begin with what's ahead of $)

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Working around this could be escaping the $ sign (making sure it isn't interpreted as a special character), something like "\$\$double_dollars\$\$"

Comment: `str.replace('$$double_dollars$$', '$$$$still_double_dollars$$$$');`

Comment: @H.Figueiredo Yes, `$` is a RegExp special character, but there's no RegExp in the question.

Comment: @Teemu String.replace will use a RegExp if provided, so yeah if Javascript considers: replace(something)  that "something" is a RegExp, then there will be RegExp in the question.

Comment: @H.Figueiredo JavaScript doesn't consider that "something" being a RegExp, if a string was provided. It's a string, and it is not implicitly converted to a RegExp. ["_\[A string\] is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters).

Comment: @Teemu you're correct! I was thinking that Javascript was interpreting the string as RegExp literal, my bad. (I would still consider this behaviour similar to RegExp, given $ is selecting some part of the match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MDN docs for [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (as what @Alex states), there is a list of special patterns which are evaluated accordingly and one of them is what you're using.

The special pattern is as follows:

- `$$` inserts a `$`

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for the full list of special patterns.

And as what @H.Figueiredo has commented, you can escape the dollar signs or follow one of the answers posted seconds after this answer.

Answer (score 2):

See: [MDN - String.prototype.replace # Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

> The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns:
>
> ```
> Pattern   Inserts  
> $$        Inserts a "$".  
> $&        Inserts the matched substring.  
> $`        Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.  
> $'        Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.  
> $n        Where n is a positive integer less than 100, inserts the nth parenthesized  
>           submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object. 
>           Note that this is 1-indexed.
> ```

```js
let str = '$$double_dollars$$'
console.log(str.replace('$$double_dollars$$', '$$$$yes_double_dollars$$$$'));
// => $$yes_double_dollars$$
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [passing a replacement String to `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

`$` is a special character. To express a literal `$`, use `$$`.

```js
let str = '$$double_dollars$$'
console.log(str.replace('$$double_dollars$$', '$$$$result$$$$'));
```